# wrong number of indices inside [], expected 5

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm having a problem with my code. Ive made a multidimensional array to store elements of a person.

Now visual studio is telling me that i have 2 diffrent errors in my code.

First one is: wrong number of indices inside [], expected , and the second error message i get is: cannot implicitly convert type `string[*,*]` to `string[*,*,*,*,*]`

The code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //wil je meer vrienden in de array pas hier het aantal aan :)
    int vrienden = 2;

    //maak array. de comma in de brackets is voor meer items, eerste waarde voor hoeveel mensen, tweede aantal elementen
    string[, , , ,] vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5];
    //^^ here i get the error code of cannot implicitly convert type 'string[*,*] to string[*,*,*,*,*]'

    Console.WriteLine("welkom bij het online vriendenboekje!");
    Console.WriteLine("hier kan je een antaal elementen van je vrienden opslaan");

    //vul de array met de elementen / vraag de mensen voor input
    for (int i = 0; i < vrienden; ++i)
    {
        Console.Write("Vul hier de naam in van je vriend -->");
        vriendenarray[i, 0] = Console.ReadLine(); //<-- here i get the error message of wrong number of indices inside []
        Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favoriete kleur in -->");
        vriendenarray[i, 1] = Console.ReadLine(); 
        Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favourite eten in -->");
        vriendenarray[i, 2] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favourite seizoen in -->");
        vriendenarray[i, 3] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favourite dier in -->");
        vriendenarray[i, 4] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //leest/displayed wat er allemaal is ingevuld
    for(int i = 0; i < vrienden; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vriend nummer {0} is {1} en zijn favoriete elementen zijn {2}{3}{4}", i, vriendenarray[i, 0], vriendenarray[i, 1], vriendenarray[i, 2], vriendenarray[i, 3], vriendenarray[i, 4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You must set all dimensions: `string[,,,,] vriendenarray = new string[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`

Comment: ..or `string[,] vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5];`

Comment: or even var vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5];

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thank you it compiles now without any problem. When i run the code i enter evertyhing but when i enter the last element the code just exits out. I'll have to look into that now. But thank you Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually working with **2D** array: please, note that you always address it as

```
vriendenarray[x, y]
```

where `x` and `y` some values. That's why

```
string[,] vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5];

...
```

**Edit**: I suggest implementing a *tailored class* with *properties*, e.g.

```
public class Vriend {
  public string Naam {get; set;}
  ...
  public string Dier {get; set;}
}
```

then you can work with evident **1D** array:

```
// Now we have an array of friend (not misterious 2d array of strings)
Vriend[] vriendenarray = new Vriend[vrienden];

// We create friends
for (int i = 0; i < vriendenarray.Length; ++i)
  vriendenarray[i] = new Vriend();

for (int i = 0; i < vriendenarray.Length; ++i) {
  // Please, note how it's easy now: we assign Naam, not second index 0
  Console.Write("Vul hier de naam in van je vriend -->");
  vriendenarray[i].Naam = Console.ReadLine();  
  ...  
  Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favourite dier in -->");
  vriendenarray[i].Dier = Console.ReadLine();
}

// for each vriend in vriendenarray is more readable
foreach (var vriend in vriendenarray)
{
    // String interpolation allows us to put code - vriend.Naaam - within string
    Console.WriteLine($"Vriend nummer {vriend.Naaam}...");
}
```

Comment: I only added a variable there to make it easier to expand the sum of persons i want to add to the program. also thanks for pointing out that its a 2D array. i tought i was working with a 5D array so i had 1 person with 5 elements including his name.

Comment: @Dashcarwash: I suggest implementing a *tailored class* with *properties* (`FriendName`..`Animal`) and turning **2D** into **1D** one

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! As usual, Visual Studio is right ;)

By saying `string[, , , ,]`, you're declaring an array with five dimensions. But you're initializing an array with two dimensions.

Due to your remaining code, I'd assume that you want a two-dimensional array. You can declare this with either `string[,] vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5];` or `var vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5];`.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a dimension to your list and would like to assign another demincion, this code corrected, but it makes no sense to declare all these demenciones:

```
string[,] vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5];
```

This code will work for you but I think you don't have to declare all these tables:

```
//wil je meer vrienden in de array pas hier het aantal aan :)
int vrienden = 2;

//maak array. de comma in de brackets is voor meer items, eerste waarde voor hoeveel mensen, tweede aantal elementen
string[,,,,] vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5,1,1,1];
//^^ here i get the error code of cannot implicitly convert type 'string[*,*] to string[*,*,*,*,*]'

Console.WriteLine("welkom bij het online vriendenboekje!");
Console.WriteLine("hier kan je een antaal elementen van je vrienden opslaan");

//vul de array met de elementen / vraag de mensen voor input
for (int i = 0; i < vrienden; ++i)
{
    Console.Write("Vul hier de naam in van je vriend -->");
    vriendenarray[i, 0, 0, 0, 0] = Console.ReadLine(); //<-- here i get the error message of wrong number of indices inside []
    Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favoriete kleur in -->");
    vriendenarray[i, 1, 0, 0, 0] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favourite eten in -->");
    vriendenarray[i, 2, 0, 0, 0] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favourite seizoen in -->");
    vriendenarray[i, 3, 0, 0, 0] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Vul hier zijn/haar favourite dier in -->");
    vriendenarray[i, 4, 0, 0, 0] = Console.ReadLine();
}

//leest/displayed wat er allemaal is ingevuld
for (int i = 0; i < vrienden; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Vriend nummer {0} is {1} en zijn favoriete elementen zijn {2}{3}{4}", i, vriendenarray[i, 0, 0, 0, 0], vriendenarray[i, 1, 0, 0, 0], vriendenarray[i, 2, 0, 0, 0], vriendenarray[i, 3, 0, 0, 0], vriendenarray[i, 4, 0, 0, 0]);
}
```

Comment: thank you for visualizing it. It made me understand what i was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create 5 dimensional array you must do like below:

```
string[,,,,] vriendenarray = new string[vrienden, 5,1,1,1];
```

Your declaration is wrong , according to this mistake you shoud correct assignments such as:

```
 vriendenarray[i, 0] = Console.ReadLine();
```

to

```
 vriendenarray[i, 0,0,0,0] = Console.ReadLine();
```

becouse vriendenarray has 5 dimension

Comment: Thank you sir, i was wachting this yt tutorial about arrays since its my first project working with them and he was using 2 dimensions. I tought I could do just the same but with 5 hahaha. Didnt work out to great. I now know how to use arrays. Thanks to you guys. cheers